# How can I make a keybind involving xdotool in Openbox?

Tags: openbox

I'm running Openbox 3.5.2 (on Lubuntu 13.10) by logging into Openbox session.

In an Openbox session, if I run `xdotool mousemove 1000 5 click 3` from a terminal, the mouse cursor moves to the specified blank position on the desktop; then a mouse right-click is executed to open the right-click menu of Openbox.

So I made the following keybind in `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`:

```
<keybind key="W-space">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>xdotool mousemove 1000 5 click 3</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

and reconfigured Openbox. But when I press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> all I see is that the mouse cursor moves to the designated position; the right-click menu doesn't appear.

How can I cause the right-click menu to appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and wait until the `mousemove` has completed, sometimes things get out of sync if your system is slow. You can put in a delay ( with `sleep` or `xdotool`'s own `--delay`. That always delays and slows down things. You should therefore first try:

```
xdotool mousemove --sync 1000 5 click 3
```

As `--sync` doesn't wait if nothing needs to be done. If that doesn't help you 
can alwasy put in an extra delay with `sleep`:

```
xdotool mousemove --sync 1000 5
sleep 0.2
xdotool click 3
```

Comment: `xdotool mousemove 1000 5 click 3` works when run from the terminal; so I don't think it's an issue of system speed. `xdotool mousemove --sync 1000 5 click 3` gives the same result.

Comment: But I made a bash script of your last suggestion, the one with `sleep`, and that worked from inside rc.xml.

Comment: @vasat it was never completely clear to me what happens with --sync, sometimes it seemed to help sometimes not. I don't like to put in `sleep` statements, but when they are necessary then it must be.

Comment: Yes, I left out `--sync` and things work fine. I tried reducing sleep's value but at some point it became touch-n-go depending, I guess, on what else was going.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the click is executing before you release <kbd>super</kbd>, and Openbox distinguishes between a click and <kbd>modifier</kbd>+click. The cleanest solution is to use `xdotool` to also send a keyup event:

```
xdotool mousemove 1000 5 keyup Super_L click 3
```

Using `sleep` as Timo suggested also works as long as you release <kbd>super</kbd> before `sleep` returns (thus the hit or miss success with a lower sleep value).

While probably not relevant in your case, if you wanted to execute another keystroke using <kbd>super</kbd> immediately after `xdotool` returns, without releasing and repressing the key, you can put a keydown event later in the command. In my testing I have been unable to release the key faster than `xdotool` executes, and the keydown event helps to ensure expected behavior.

Comment: +1 My tint2 start menu is complete... (it uses xprop for the _NET_WORKAREA atom)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the Openbox menu when you press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>spacebar</kbd> then you could do it with just

```
<keybind key="W-space">
  <action name="ShowMenu">
    <menu>root-menu</menu>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

This works all the time even if you have a window in fullscreen.